# Chamar Barra de Compartilhamento, após a imagem ser carregada com 'lazyload'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou utilizando a plugin (jQuery.Lazy();) para carregar minhas imagens.

LINK: http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/

Ela possui esse callback:

```
// called after an element was successfully handled
afterLoad: function(element) {
    var imageSrc = element.data('src');
    console.log('image "' + imageSrc + '" was loaded successfully');
},
```

O que eu pretendo fazer é chamar uma barra de compartilhamento, após cada imagem ser carregada, estou utilizando a share-bar do pessoal da Globo.com (https://github.com/globocom/share-bar)

Mas não estou conseguindo carregar ela ai.. .

Eu até importei ela com `.html(<div class="share-bar"...)`. Ela carrega, mas não é exibida.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Eu cheguei a testar isso:

```
afterLoad: function(element) {
                    var imageSrc = element.data('src');
                    new ShareBar({
                        'selector': '.share-nn',
                        'buttonWidth': 24,
                        'buttonPadding': 2,
                        'networks': [
                            'facebook',
                            'twitter',
                            'whatsapp',
                            'google',
                            'email'
                        ]
                    });
                }
```

Mas ele criou, em cada imagem, a mesma quantidade de barras de acordo com a quantidade de imagens, tipo, 10 imagens, em cada um ele criou 10 barras.

Comment: Em que ponto ficou? o que já tentou fazer? assim do zero é complicado ajudar :/

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o que eu cheguei a fazer e onde estou parado..

Comment: Você já tentou fazer assim $(function() { $('.sua-imagem').lazy({ afterLoad... }) });

Comment: está assim atualmente: http://prntscr.com/b55rtm